# PHP Upload and showing PDF file BLOB corrupt

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdf, blob

I am trying to make a feature on my webpage for uploading files to a MySQL database and then showing/making the user able to download the file later.
The upload of a PDF seems fine, but when opening the downloaded file, Adobe tells me the file is corrupt. When trying to show the file in the browser, it says it can't open the file. Please help

Upload script:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO f_driver VALUES('', ?, 'Datablad', ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $type);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $data);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $pid);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $uid);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Script for downloading/showing (attachment changed to inline)

```
require_once("../include/pdo_connect.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$table = $_GET['table'];
$stat = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = ?");
$stat->bindParam(1, $id);
$stat->execute();
$row = $stat->fetch();
$name = $row['name'];
$type = $row['mime'];
$content = $row['data'];
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $content;
```

Comment: As you dont use a column name list in the INSERT command. It could be that the data values are not going to the columns you think. You dont do any error checking after the INSERT so this make the above possibility even more likely

Comment: `SELECT * FROM $_GET['table'];` Really dangerous

Comment: Your first debugging step in such a case should always be that you open such a downloaded file in a text or even hex editor - and then check if there’s any PHP error messages or similar in there.

Comment: The $_GET['table'] is due to multiple file tables depending on the product type.
Otherwise I could make multiple queries changing with a switch statement? I will try using the column list to determine the specific type of data for my INSERT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. It seemed that PDO had a default buffer size of 1MiB. This was changed with a $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024*1024*16); for 16 MB. Then everything went perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Could you kindly provide a sample of the structure of your table?
It seems most likely that the `data` field type of your table isn't provisioned for large data sets and cuts off data after a specific amount of bytes. Have you tried a different field type? Perhaps `LONGTEXT` or `BLOB`?

Comment: The structure is as follows.
id - INT Auto inctrement primary key,
name - varchar(255),
document_type - varchar,
mime - varchar,
data - MEDIUMBLOB,
product_id - INT foreign key,
owner - INT foreign key,

Comment: Do you base64 encode your data before inserting? If not, try that. Then when displaying or extracting the data from the table, base64 decode it.